# What are the top 5 Plugins that every Umbraco Website SHOULD have?

Tags: plugins, umbraco

What would be your top 5 picks for Umbraco Plugins/packages for an Umbraco website?

Comment: This is off topic for Stack Overflow. That said, I try to avoid using 'plugins' as much as possible. The only ones I would use are uSync, Vorto and Umbraco Forms if forced by a PM.

Comment: Why off-topic? I think that it can be treaten as "software tools" used at top of Umbraco CMS (regarding to: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). What you think @Anth12?

Comment: Because it is opinion based, there is no real answer.

Comment: The Whole Idea behind asking this question was to seek opinion of experienced Umbraco developers regarding their usage of Packages/plugins.

Comment: @piya if that's your intention then it wouldn't take much to rework it to fit the guidelines.

Answer (score 3):

My Top5:

1. **Diplo Trace Log Viewer** && **Diplo Audit Log Viewer** (https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/diplo-trace-log-viewer/, https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/diplo-audit-log-viewer/) - browse logs directly from the backoffice.
2. **Nested Content** (https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/nested-content/) - grouped data tapes from specific document type in single data type in another (SIC! Soon available inside the Core).
3. **Umbraco Core Property Value Converters** (https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/umbraco-core-property-value-converters) -this package implements property editor converters for the Umbraco Core property editors.
4. **F.A.L.M. Housekeeping / unVersion** (https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/falm-housekeeping, https://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/unversion/) - cleaning around versions and logs inside the database.
5. **uSync** (https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/usync/) - keeping sync beetween enviroments.

There is a lot more of them TBH :) It's hard to choose the best ones. I like e-commerce packages (**TeaCommerce**, **Marchello**), blogging packages (**uBlogsy**, **Articulate**) and testing all interesting packages made by community for special use cases.

It's also definitely worth to check **Ismail Mayat**'s presentation from this year **Umbraco PL Fest**, about his Top 10 fo packages for Umbraco: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2MvoletQNzs.

Comment: +1 for uSync and Nested Content. uSync makes multi-developer working and deployment a lot easier (have tried without). Nested Content makes complicated document models much easier to editors to handle.